# Rails_admin custom partials are not used in Integration tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, capybara, guard, rails-admin

I'm currently working on a rails_admin application which uses a custom partial :
Here is an extract of my rails_admin.rb initializer:

```
edit do
  field :propositions do
    partial 'form_propositions'
  end
end
```

I wrote integration tests using capybara and launched them with guard: all my tests are green and when I use 'save_and_open_page' in my tests suites I can confirm that my custom partial is used by capybara.
But if I launch my tests with 'rake test:integration' my tests fail: with the 'save_and_open_page' method I can see that my custom partial is not used and instead I have the original rails_admin form...

Do you have any idea of what is happening ?
Thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

RailsAdmin adds a rake task to the rake :environment task that turns off the loading of the RailsAdmin initializer. This means rake tasks don't load custom actions, partials, etc.

Since guard is not started up by a rake task, all the customizations are properly loaded.

To turn off this performance "optimization" so that you can test RailsAdmin customizations in a rake task, add the following to your Rakefile:

```
task :default => [:load_rails_admin_initializer]
task :load_rails_admin_initializer do
  ENV['SKIP_RAILS_ADMIN_INITIALIZER'] = 'false'
end
```